# How to parse my json data in Android

Tags: android, json

I receive this data from HTTP:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "NOME": "Nome 1",
        "APELIDO": "Apelido 1",
        "CATEGORIA": "1"
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "NOME": "Nome 2",
        "APELIDO": "Apelido 2",
        "CATEGORIA": "1"
    }
]
```

How I can parse this data on Android `ID = int` and `CATEGORIA = int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
{
    try {
        JSONObject eachObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        // Getting items from the json array
        int id = eachObject.getInt("ID");
        int cattegory = eachObject.getInt("CATEGORIA");
        String nome= eachObject.getString("NOME");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: How i get string from json array?
-> "NOME":"Nome 1"

Comment: You can do `String nome= eachObject.getString("NOME");`

Comment: It will fail if "ID" contains non integer value. int id = eachObject.getInt("ID");

Comment: Please read OPs question carefully. It clearly states `ID = int` and `CATEGORIA = int`.

Comment: Yeah.. agreed. My concern is the json which is mentioned, in that "ID" has value as string type.. I am saying its not correct... It should be int type.. If we make it as int type that we are sure that the value will always be integer.

Answer (score 1):

Just in-case if you are defining the json then you can change it to:
[{"ID":1,"NOME":"Nome 1","APELIDO":"Apelido 1","CATEGORIA":1},{"ID":2,"NOME":"Nome 2","APELIDO":"Apelido 2","CATEGORIA":1}]

As Json supports int type then why to take such values in String. Its better that we directly take them in int.

For converting ID and CATEGORIA to integer, you need to do it manually. As in json data its string, you need to first take it in string and then manually convert it to int by using Integer.parseInt method.

I would suggest to use com.google.gson library for parsing. Below is the model class (Data.java) for Json mentioned by you. You can use Data.parse(stringJson) to get list of Data.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Data {
    /**
     * @SerializedName should contain json key name
     */
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("ID")
    private String mId;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("NOME")
    private String mNome;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("APELIDO")
    private String mApelido;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("CATEGORIA")
    private String mCategoria;

    public static ArrayList<Data> parse(String json) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Data>>() {
        }.getType();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ArrayList<Data> dataList = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
        return dataList;
    }
}
```

Comment: No you don't have to parse it as String first. Please refer the source code.`getInt(String name)` will internally call `JSON.toInteger()` which will handle String too. It does `return (int) Double.parseDouble((String) value);`

Comment: Though gson may be another way to go there is no real need for it as android has good support for json parsing.

Comment: That may not be correct approach as Json Data type is String. Ideally, Json should be updated in such way that the field has integer. As per current json, it is possible that it is not actually an integer and our complete parsing will fail in that case. Hence its always better to parse it to string first.

Comment: Its always good practice to get data in model. Instead of considering it just as normal JsonObject. Gson provides good way to directly parse json string in java object. Hence I prefer Gson.

Comment: I agree some people prefer using JSON but generalizing `As in json data its string, you need to first take it in string and then manually convert it to int by using Integer.parseInt method` is wrong. If that was true developers would never provide support for `getInt(String name)` method :)

Comment: Agreed. Hence I would recommend to change json format to have strong binding which will make sure that ID will always be int type. If Json supports int type then why to take that ID as String...

Comment: Ideally json should be: [{"ID":1,"NOME":"Nome 1","APELIDO":"Apelido 1","CATEGORIA":1},{"ID":2,"NOME":"Nome 2","APELIDO":"Apelido 2","CATEGORIA":1}]

Comment: Okie :) One more thing to point in your way you will have to handle `NumberFormat` Exception yourself. If you use `getInt()` you will get null for non integer values.

Comment: Agreed. I think outcome of our discussion is better to define Json properly. If we don't have any option then we can parse it blindly assuming that the string will always have integer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    String json = "give the json value here";
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

    for(int i = 0, N = jsonArray.length(); i < N; i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        int id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("id").toString());
        int CATEGORIA = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("CATEGORIA").toString());
    }
}
} catch (JSONException e) {
    //handle exception
}
```